Example of a name clash between enum names and mixin-class methods/attributes?
The Python Enum tutorial recommends using upper case names for Enum members "to help avoid issues with name clashes between mixin-class methods/attributes and enum names".
What would be an example of such a name clash?

Also, would be awesome if someone could clarify why this is getting downvoted.

@MarkRansom What's stupid about it? It's a simple question that touches some fairly obscure aspects of the language (accessing one enum member through another) and which does not have an answer here (which is probably why some chatbots spew nonsense when you ask them).
I did imagine an example of my own (see answer below), but maybe there's a better one.
The reason I asked for one was, I want to know how important for my use case the uppercase convention would be. So I wanted to get an idea when I'd encounter a name clash.

I was just trying to help imagine a reason why you might be downvoted.  None of those votes was mine.

The ability to access one enum member directly from another is sometimes useful and can lead to such a clash. This is how you can access one member from another in the case of a simple enum:
import enum 

class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    foo = 1
    bar = 2

foo = MyEnum.foo

foo.bar # access to MyEnum.bar <MyEnum.bar: 2>

Now imagine a custom enum where you mix in a class that has a method called bar() which is the same as the name of one of the members of your enum:
class MixinClass():
    def bar(self):
        print ('bar method') 

class MyEnum(MixinClass, enum.Enum):
    foo = 1
    bar = 2

foo = MyEnum.foo

foo.bar # <MyEnum.bar: 2>

# but
foo.bar() # TypeError: 'MyEnum' object is not callable 

i.e. because the name of the enum member matches that of the method, one  cannot access the inherited .bar() method in the usual way (if there's a workaround, I'm not aware of it).

The first part of the quote is more relevant, I think.

Because Enums are used to represent constants, and to help avoid
issues with name clashes between mixin-class methods/attributes and
enum names, we strongly recommend using UPPER_CASE names for members,
and will be using that style in our examples.

The fact that class-level constants in ordinary classes aren't common, and thus their attributes don't use the uppercase convention, then makes conflicts rare.
But anytime you inherit from classes, there is a chance of a name collision, either between names used by more than one base class, or between an inherited name and an attribute you want to use. It's something you need to be aware of: conflicts between base classes are usually handled by inheriting from a wrapper that renames an attribute, and conflicts with your own desired names are usually worked around by choosing non-conflicting names in the child. (As an aside, name-mangling can be employed by a class that expects a child class to conflict with its own attribute.)
